# How to interface JADE with any other Front End?

Tags: java, agents-jade

I am working on a project which uses JADE over a network.

Visit http://jade.tilab.com for more details.

However, I want the JADE to interface with some normal GUI, say HTML. My aime is that I want a Computer which doesn't have JADE installed, to be accessing the JADE network, say via RPC or any other non-JADE interface. Hope I have framed the Q correctly and thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

We have a [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) front end to our JADE network. The front end uses the [JadeGateway](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/wrapper/gateway/JadeGateway.html) class as the interface to the Jade environment. The documentation is not great but this [article](http://jade.cselt.it/doc/tutorials/JadeGateway.pdf) got us most of the way there.

Comment: Yes, this was the only article that saved me. The source code can be downloaded from [http://people.inf.elte.hu/kelemen/jade/JadeGateWaySimple_source.zip](http://people.inf.elte.hu/kelemen/jade/JadeGateWaySimple_source.zip) except some minor configuration in eclipse the app should be working right away.