# Connecting JADE with WAMP

Tags: wamp, agents-jade

Hi Java Agent DEvelopment Framework developers! I want to use WAMP with JADE, can I do that, simple because I am well averse with WAMP. Or does JADE recommend only Java related technologies to be interfaced? Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use WAMP for developing some front-end logic. You can do this but you probably have to develop JADE as a web service which requires it to be deployed to a web container like tomcat. and communicate with JADE agents via SOAP messages or use tomcat connectors to integrate apache web server with tomcat and service the requests using Java Servlets. Either way you need some Java web container.

Comment: do i necessary need it to be hosted on a web container? I mean I cannot use traditional JADE and WAMP, need it to convert it to web service?

Comment: It does not have to be a web service. You can have Servlets running on tomcat servicing the requests from Apache Server. JADE being Java code needs a JVM and Apache server is just a HTTP web server. The only way I can imagine communication between JADE agents and Apache Server is through web requests. You can use Zend Server which has a Java connector out of the box. [link](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Platform/about.htm)

Comment: I have developed a JADE web application using JSP/Servlets some time back. For your reference, I have posted the code that helped me getting started in your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851328/how-to-interface-jade-with-any-other-front-end) My advise would be to just use Tomcat server and develop your front end logic using JSF which makes life lot easier. Please feel free to ask any questions regarding JADE.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark the answer accepted, if it has helped you in solving the problem atleast partly.